# Jquery - Get value of other dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have 2 dropdowns. When I select one I need to get the value of the other dropdown too.

When I select the dropdown with the ID `#collo`, I also need the value of the dropdown with the ID `#vervoerder_id`. But with the code below I can't get the value of the select with the ID # `vervoerder_id`. It stays empty.

This is my code in jquery

```js
$('#collo').change(function(){
    $('#collos_gewicht').empty();
    var value = $("#collo").val();
    var vervoerder $('#vervoerder_id').val();
    var dataString = 'value=' + value + '&vervoerder=' + vervoerder;
    $.ajax({
        url: "collos_gewicht.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType:"html",
        type: "post",
        success: function(data){
           $('#collos_gewicht').append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<select name="vervoerder_id">
<option value="1">PostNL</option>
<option value="2">PostNL Pickup Locatie</option>
<option value="3">UPS</option>
<option value="5">TNT Pallet</option>
<option value="6">Zelf afhalen</option>
</select>

<select name="collo" id="collo">
<option value="">Choose the number of collos</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Put     ```var vervoerder = $('#vervoerder_id').val();``` with id on select with name vervoerder_id

Comment: Your selectbox doesn't have `id` i.e : vervoerder_id .

Answer (score 1):

Your first `select` does not have and `id` so the `#vervoerder_id` selector will not work.

Either add an `id` attribute on the `select` element, or use a correct selector

```
var vervoerder = $('select[name="vervoerder_id"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `id` of the other `select` does not exist, only a `name`. Fix:

```
<select name="vervoerder_id" id="vervoerder_id">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.
By adding an id to vervoerder_id the problem was solved.
I've completely overseen it. Thanks a lot!!